# python: get first value from list as value on dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an array of dictionaries. Each dictionary has an "id" as its key and a corresponding list attached to it.

I want to iterate over the list of dictionaries and access the first liste item from each dictionary's value.

As an idea , the data structure is as follows:

```
[ {"abc": [1,2,3]}, {"def":[4,5,6]} ]
```

I'd want to iterate through and get [1,4]

Comment: See the duplicate; apply this to each dictionary and extract the first element of the resulting lists: `[next(d.itervalues())[0] for d in inputlist]`

Answer (score 2):

You want to get the value of each dictionary, using [`dict.values()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values), which returns a list of values. Because you know that the dictionary only has one value, the first value is the list you want.

So, you can do this:

```
first_items = []
for d in my_dicts:
    first_items.append(d.values()[0][0])
```

You can shorten this into a list comprehension as well.

```
first_items = [d.values()[0][0] for d in my_dicts]
```

Comment: perfect. that is exactly what I was looking for. I was trying to use iteritems() with no progress